# Extracting Data From API

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a issue wrapping my head around how to extract the data from my backend api. The backend returns the data:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"What"},{"id":2,"text":"Hi"}]
```

My issue is that when using setState I only get the second object in the state when I want both.

Test.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Test extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages:{},
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/message/?format=json')
  .then(response =>response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.map(message => this.setState({messages:message}))

    })


  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>
          {console.log(this.state)}
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Test;
```

Instead of returning a state of :

```
message: {{"id":1,"text":"What"},
    {"id":2,"text":"Hi"}
}
```

The console gives me three outputs:

```
{messages: {…}}
messages
:
{}
__proto__
:
Object
Test.js:25 
{messages: {…}}
messages
:
{id: 1, text: "What"}
__proto__
:
Object
Test.js:25 
{messages: {…}}
messages
:
{id: 2, text: "Hi"}
__proto__
:
Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting only one message in the state. First one, then replacing it with the second:

```
then(data => {
    data.map(message => this.setState({messages:message}))
})
```

If you want both messages save both in the state and then show them in the render with a map:

```
then(data => this.setState({messages:data}))
```

Render:

```
render(){
    return(
      <div>
         {this.state.messages.map(message => <h1>{message}</h1>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the state value every time map setsState, if you use this instead, it should work

```
  componentDidMount(){
     fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/message/?format=json')
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then(messages =>  this.setState({messages}))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

```
data => {
    this.setState({messages:data})
}
```

you are calling setState twice, so the first message is overwritten by the second.